# Blender 2.8 Eevee Transparent Background Output

Tags: transparency, video, eevee-render-engine

Using Eevee on 2.8 to create some VFX, however, all the video renders I output still have a black background and not transparent. I have selected Alpha channel to be "transparent" to no avail!

Can someone please help!

Many thanks,

Andrew

Comment: It is worth noting that it does show transparent in the viewport and when I render inside blender. However, the issue is when I output the render, the background is now black and not transparent.

Comment: Make sure the file format that you are rendering to supports alpha

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,  Render an Png or Tiff Image sequences which supports RGB + alpha  instead of Video. 
Secondly,  To enable transperancy go to Render Settings in the properties panel and under Film go to alpha and select Transperant from the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, posting just in case anyone else comes across this. Removing a volume scatter node from the world material fixed the transparency issue, with it there it always rendered as black.

Answer (score 1):

Check the compositing, had the same issue because I forgot to uncheck "use alpha" in the composite node.

Comment: This is the solution